# how to go to next activity when database got cleared ?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm tying to go to a new activity after I cleared my database. You can visualy see that the database is cleared but after that notihing happens. But another acctivity should start.
this is my code:

```
    public void resetGameTable(){   
    objDbHelper = new DatabaseConnector(this);
    objDbHelper.open();
    objDbHelper.resetTable(DatabaseOpenHelper.SCORE_TABLE,DatabaseOpenHelper.createScoreTable,null);
    objDbHelper.close();

    Intent intent = new Intent(ResetDatabase.this, main.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Need more context of where you are calling this from. Is it the UI thread? What is `main`?

Comment: main = my Main_activity. i'm calling this from a other activity wich is summond by a button on the menu. hoped it helped

Comment: comment out all the `objDbHeler` code and see if it starts the Activity then